# Designing a secure IM protocol

Tags: encryption, public-key, protocol-design

I haven't been programming much lately, so I figured I would make an encrypted instant-messaging program (read: Skype clone) with groups to hone my skills. That's not important though, I can do that. The problem is that I know almost nothing about cryptography, so I figured I'd ask here so I don't discover down the road that my way of doing crypto is all wrong and I have to remake everything.

Here's my plan:

- When a client connects, it generates a keypair (or loads one from disk) and sends the public key off to the server.
- The server broadcasts the public keys of everyone in a group chat to everyone else.
- When a client sends a message, it encrypts (with NaCl's crypto_box) the message many times, once with each public key. Then it sends all of them off to the server, including information about which encrypted message goes to which client.
- The server simply forwards the messages to the recipients, and the recipient decrypts it with his own private key and the sender's public key (again with NaCl's crypto_box).

There will of course be authentication, so someone can't just send their public key to the server, pretending to be someone else.

I have no idea how secure that method is, or if it can even work. If this is not optimal, how would you do it?

Comment: One obvious issue is that you can send a different message to each recipient with that scheme.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Why is that a problem?

Comment: Hmmm… the authorization part is a bit *“undescribed”*. ;) How and where in that protocol are you planning to implement authorization? I'm asking because it's an important part of what you're planning to do… and doing it wrong might break your protocol quicker than anything else. (Without that information, answers would have to guess if authorization would be able to kill Schrödinger’s cat or not – and when it comes to crypto, the worst is to be assumed.)

Comment: @e-sushi I'm planning to do a simple username-password thing. Right username/password, and the server accepts it. Wrong, and you get kicked off the socket.

Comment: Since you'll probably don't want to force clients to do the same "simple username-password" thing every time a client interacts with the server… how are you planning to verify authorization whenever clients share keys and/or messages? In other words: how and where are you going to store the temporary username-password authorization, how is that authorization transported between clients and the server (and vice-versa), and - *what I'm actually hinting at* – where in your protocol can I find (the verification of) that authorization? (*hint-hint*)

Comment: @e-sushi Sorry, English is not my first language. Once a client connects, it'll have 5 seconds to give a valid username/password until it gets kicked off. If it does give a valid username/password, it'll be given a session key (stored in a database), which it'll use in every other API call. If it gives an invalid session key to any of the other calls, it either gets kicked off or simply gets an error message (haven't really decided yet).

Comment: No worries, I'm not English-native either. ;) It would be cool if you could edit your question to add a description of that authorization part (the comment I upvoted). It'll make it easier for others to analyze your plan/protocol (fact is, not everyone takes the time to check the comment-area to see if any additional information like that was provided). Oh, and welcome to Crypto.SE btw.

Comment: @CrateMuncher: An example of the issue codes-in-chaos alludes to is this:
I send you "Hello, can you hear me?" and I send e-sushi "Crate, can you confirm you promised to send me £1000". You then reply "Yes, of course", and e-sushi thinks you've agreed to pay me money.

Comment: @figlesquidge You got a minor error in logic there, because I would reply “Hey, I'm e-sushi… not Crate” when you send me that message.

Comment: Well the point was to exploit the fact users think every message is sent to everyone. If you'd rather, I could say "Crate, for the record, would you confirm ...".  If this example didn't work, I'd get a witness less irritating than e-sushi :-P

Comment: @figlesquidge Topping of my annoyance, I think you meant to write: *An example of the issue codes-in-chaos alludes to is this: I send you "Hello, can you hear me?" and e-sushi sends a message saying "Crate, can you confirm you promised to send me £1000?". You then reply "Yes, of course", and e-sushi might think you've agreed to pay money because e-sushi doesn't know you are actually responding to the "Hello, can you hear me?" message.* Yet, I think the different keys could/would prevent that (encrypted message for figlesquidge would be garbage when e-sushi decodes it using his private key).

Comment: @figlesquidge Interesting… you just made me realize this protocol can not be used for a group chat because it actually fits one-to-one communication only (unless all public keys are shared with everyone in the group – making the protocol needlessly complicated and the transport-overhead rather large).

Comment: One thing you also need to consider: what is your threat model? What kinds of threats are you protecting against? In the current incarnation, the server is all-powerful and must be trusted. If the server is compromised, an attacker can issue his own public key instead of any user's.

Comment: See, this is exactly why I consulted you guys before actually doing anything. I would have never thought of that. Are there any other ways you could solve this problem that I haven't thought of?

Comment: The problem isn't even well defined until you have a threat model.

Answer (score 3):

I think the very first question before diving into designing the protocol would be to ask yourself what kind of secure communication do you want? Namely, there are two options to consider when it comes to communication between the IM users:

1. For the **client-server secure communication**, there are two directions to consider:

   1. From *“sender to server”*, you would have to encrypt the message with the public key of the server (assuming using public key encryption).
   2. From *“sender to recipients”*, the server would encrypt each message with the respective recipients' public key (assuming using public key encryption). However, if you are consider using symmetric encryption, a good reference for protocol would be the SSL/TLS protocol that is used widely.
2. For the **end-to-end secure communication**, it would be difficult to implement for group message but simpler for individual message. It means that the sender will encrypt the message with a predefined encryption key, and only people who know the encryption key is able to decrypt the message. Sharing the predefined encryption with a group might compromise on the overall security.

Once decided on the framework type, you can add additional information to the payload (i.e. message) to ensure there is authentication, non-repudiation, data integrity, etc. A good reference would be the SSL/TLS protocol.